# Database saving strange characters no matter what I do

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding

I've searched high and low and used every possible workaround but can't get it to work. In an admin form the article name and text, if it's in Russian, it gets saved as a bunch of strange characters.

I have my html `<meta>` tags set, PHP header also set to UTF8, using `mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $db)`, and in my database the article title and article text rows are set to utf8_general_ci.

Also my table collation is set to utf8_general_ci; I can't get anything to work!

```
if(isset($_POST['articleName'])){
    mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $mysqli_connect);
    if (($_POST['articleName'] == null) || ($_POST['cat'] == null)) {
        $errorMsg = "Insert at least article name and choose category";
    }else{
        $articleName = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $_POST['articleName']);
        $articleText = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['articleText'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $catList = implode(',', $_POST['cat']);  //gets all checked boxes
        if ($_POST['videolink'] != ""){
            $videolink = str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $_POST['videolink']);
        }else{
            $videolink = "";
        }
        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, "SELECT id FROM table WHERE title='$articleName'");
        $row_check = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if ($row_check > 0){
            $errorMsg = "This article name is already in the database!";
        }else{
            $ins = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, "INSERT INTO table...");
```

I don't know what else I can do here, please help!

Comment: Can you show what the strange characters look like?

Comment: Also are you 10000% sure the HTML form is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Ñ†Ðµ-Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÑˆÐ°-ÑÑ‚Ð°Ñ‚Ñ‚Ñ...those are some of the letters.  I have it in between the head tags and at the top of the page right after the php tags header(...).  Do I need to set the FORM separately somehow?

Comment: Um, `mysqli_set_charset()`'s arguments should be [the other way round?](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) PHP should complain about that, though, and throw an error

Comment: Check your page is being rendered as UTF-8. In Firefox, the Page Info dialogue will contain this info, other browsers should also have something similar.

Comment: I'm not getting any error and the data gets inserted with mysqli statement.  I'm using Chrome...will try to figure out how to check that...

Comment: Fix the mysqli_set_charset() like Pekka said, execute "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character_set%'" using the connection from PHP to ensure the connection is right.  Check "SHOW CREATE TABLE table" and make sure the charset is UTF-8.  If the DB is ok, then it must be either that the form is not being submitted as UTF-8, or that the characters you're entering are not UTF-8.  My guess is the former, but for the latter, are you typing in the Russian characters, or copy+pasting from somewhere else? C+P characters from a known-good UTF-8 site instead of another source. Check Content-Type header is UTF-8.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you were right...php wasn't complaining but that was the problem.  I saw many other forums with the query written like that...that fixed it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, how are you _viewing_ the data that is saved?  It could be that the characters are saved correctly as UTF-8, but you're viewing them in a different character set.  If you're using a client, your connection settings there could be wrong, or your terminal might not support UTF-8, or if you're outputting to a webpage, the output page might not be set to UTF-8.